# Can we have a subscription specific metrics in AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Usecase is that our SNS is subscribed by multiple team's SQS in different AWS accounts.
We want to have a subscription level metrics to find out if messages are being delivered to a specific subscribed queue. Is there any way to achieve this ?